# MCP2515 library for stm32fxx

Tags: stm32f4discovery, obd-ii, can-bus, stm32f1

I am wondering with any stm32f10x or stm32f30x microcontrollers.

Now, i am working on canbus projects with mcp2515-spi module, can anyone help me to find a proper library?

Comment: when i configure MCP2515 module to listen-only mode, I just see single message all time. Anyone knows that problem?

Comment: take a look at link below. probably you can have some brainstroming:
https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/can-bus-module-shield-tutorial-for-arduino-raspberry-pi-intel-galileo/